# ReferenceError with API Google sheet

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to this and am following a tutorial which is telling me what to post as a first lesson. I am getting the error:

> "ReferenceError: "APIPullSheet" is not defined (line 8, file "Code).

Line 8 below is:

> "APIPullSheet.getRange('A2:D199').clearContent();"

Code is as follows:

```
{
    // Link the script with a spreadsheet using the unique identifier found in the spreadsheet web address
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1COPZmNRB3pd80fMbLXzi2vfTBKoDYb7rk3yCa2-cI4k');
    // Clear Columns A, B, C & D
    APIPullSheet.getRange('A2:D199').clearContent();

    // Pull the JSON data and parse it
    var url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&depth=19999";

    var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
}
```

My google sheet is setup with the right name (APIPull) and my Google sheet identifier is correct. Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, use indentation to format your code in question  and make it more readable

Comment: Is the above what you meant by indentation?